# Any ideas why folders are extracted as file name when using Archive Utility?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip to pack files for my clients to download their files. 
However when using Archive Utility on Mac, the extracted files are all in a same folder with the original file path as folder name. But if using other program to unzip with no problems. 
Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Checksums;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class ZipClass
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Check file writing status
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lpPathName"></param>
    /// <param name="iReadWrite"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr _lopen(string lpPathName, int iReadWrite);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
    public const int OF_READWRITE = 2;
    public const int OF_SHARE_DENY_NONE = 0x40;
    public readonly IntPtr HFILE_ERROR = new IntPtr(-1);
    public bool FileOccupyStatus(string vFileName)
    {
        IntPtr vHandle = _lopen(vFileName, OF_READWRITE | OF_SHARE_DENY_NONE);
        if (vHandle == HFILE_ERROR)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("File being used");
            return false;
        }
        CloseHandle(vHandle);
        //MessageBox.Show("File free");
        return true;
    }

    ZipOutputStream zos = null;
    string strBaseDir = "";
    public bool ZipFolder(string folder, string zipFile)
    {
        zos = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(zipFile));
        zos.Password = "";
        strBaseDir = folder + "\\";
        addZipEntry(strBaseDir);
        //ZipFileDictory(strBaseDir, zos, "");
        zos.Finish();
        zos.Close();
        return true;
    }

    void addZipEntry(string PathStr)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(PathStr);
        foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            addZipEntry(folder.FullName + "\\");
        }
        foreach (FileInfo item in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            if (FileOccupyStatus(item.FullName.ToString()))
            {
                if (item.Extension.ToLower() == ".pdf")
                {   
                    continue;
                }
                FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(item.FullName);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                string strEntryName = item.FullName.Replace(strBaseDir, "");
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(strEntryName);
                entry.IsUnicodeText = true;
                entry.Size = fs.Length;
                zos.PutNextEntry(entry);
                zos.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Call function from webpage:

```
....
string folder = dr["folder"].ToString().Replace("/", "\\");
ZipClass zip = new ZipClass();

folder = Server.MapPath("/data") + "\\" + folder;
try
{
    zip.ZipFolder(folder, folder + "\\media.zip");
    Response.Write("{\"status\":\"true\",\"file\":\"/" + dr["zip"] + "\"}");
}
catch
{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace backwards slashes with forward slashes in the entry name.

Check this question for example:
[How do you add a folder to a zip archive with ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363187/how-do-you-add-a-folder-to-a-zip-archive-with-icsharpcode-sharpziplib)

Comment: Not working, still the same issue. The problem is if I use other program to unzip the folder, the folder structure is correct.